# grep searchstring /etc/crontab strange behavior in BASH script

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, cron

I am working on a BASH script which creates automated backups via the crontab.  I am trying to use

```
myVARIABLE=`grep backup /etc/crontab`
```

to return lines containing "backup" if an entry has already been made.  Instead of returning lines from `/etc/crontab` it seems to be returning the output of multiple ls commands.  I have run the command

```
grep backup /etc/crontab
```

from the command line and it works as expected.  I can also grep other files via my BASH script and it returns expected results as well.  Any thoughts as to why `/etc/crontab` causes grep problems within a script?  Thanks!

Comment: Chances are you are using `myVARIABLE` or quoting something incorrectly but without more information it's impossible to tell.  Try adding snippets about what your script does after that line.  Also make sure to [describe the high-level goal you are trying to accomplish](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) so people can suggest good ways to go about it.  Putting multiple lines in a shell variable is clunky at best.

Answer (score 3):

That is because /etc/crontab contains asterisk characters (`*`), which, when not escaped, will be expanded by the shell.

Compare the output of these two commands:

```
echo $myVariable
echo "$myVariable"
```

The first command uses the variable unescaped, so the asterisk characters will be expanded to all files in the current directory. The second command is what you want, the real contents of the crontab file.